# Formula field on parent object to get last related list record field

Tags: related-list, formula-field

I'm trying to create a formula field on a parent object that will retrieve a field from the latest record in a child related list (without apex if possible). The related list is from a lookup field not a master-detail. The parent is a custom object (Sample Orders) and the child is a Docusign Status object.

Is there a way to get a field value from the last created/updated Docusign Status record in a formula field on the Sample Orders object? Again, without apex if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this without `Apex` by using `Process Builder` on `DocuSign Status`.

**Filters:** You would want to filter that the `DocuSign Status` corresponds to `Sample Order` as follows:

- Field - use your lookup as the field, but make sure you use the lookup (ends with __c) and not the relationship (has a right arrow).
- Operator - startsWith
- Type - Id
- Value - use the first three characters (key prefix) for any `Sample Order` Id. For example, if it were to `Account` you would use a filter value of 001.

**Action:** You can then set the field you want on `Sample Order` from the `DocuSign Status`.

- Action Type - Update Records
- Action Name - whatever you like
- Field Update - select the same lookup as in your filter, set type to reference, and find your field.

Comment: Been working with SF for 3 years now and have never looked at the Process Builder. Thanks Adrian!

Comment: @AdamH. It is a very cool new feature! Not without its pain points but definitely worth exploring. If your cross-object architecture is already brittle...it might push you over the edge. But in a healthy system it has room to work even before they fix the bulkification issues.

Answer (score 6):

Parent objects can't look 'down' to child objects in that way for Lookup relations. You can look 'up' to a parent (from the Child), but not down to the child (from the Parent). In fact, if you go to create such a formula, you wouldn't even see the relation to the child object.

You can look down to children when the relationship is Master/Detail, but only then to create a Roll Up Summary field which will allow you to aggregate a field on the Child record.

I don't think there is a declarative way to achieve what you are wanting to do, the way I would set about it would be a simple Apex Trigger, but you have already stipulated you would rather not use Apex.

Answer (score 1):

Through a lookup relationship, I do not believe it is possible without Apex

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a lookup field in parent object
Then write APEX trigger to populate ID of child object when it is created.