# Retrieve a field from the latest record in a child object

Tags: apex, community, workflow, process-builder, time-dependent-workflow

I am wishing to have a formula field on a parent object (Clients) that will locate a field from the latest record in a child related list (without apex). The related list is from a lookup field. The parent is a custom object (Clients) and the child is a custom object (Employers).

Can i get a field value from the last created Employers record in a formula field on the Clients object? (for example have a current employer field within the clients object which is taking the record from the latest added employer on the related list)

I have found a solution using process builder ([Formula field on parent object to get last related list record field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/34699/formula-field-on-parent-object-to-get-last-related-list-record-field/94273#94273)) but since this was posted the options etc. have changed in process builder and the instructions given in the answer are not up to date so I am finding it difficult to follow with my scenario.

Many Thanks